# Importing mp3 files metadata in Microsoft Access

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, mp3, metadata

I want to make a database of my media collection for my application. I want to create a library for that. Now what i want is that user should be able to add his own song to the database.

How can i access mp3 files metadata in my database?
How to update that database using my application.

PS: My application is a media player made in Visual Basic using Visual Studio. And i am new to databases.

Comment: Are you using VB6 or VB.Net? 2005, 2008, 2010?

Answer (score 2):

As for tag reading you can either use a pre-made library:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/

Or write your own based off the specs:

http://www.id3.org/ID3v1

http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0

(If you really want to read v2 tags, go with the library, they're a headache to deal with).

Then for database storage, if you want to store only certain items, (say, the contents of an ID3v1 tag), make a table with columns for each bit of information.